# Real-time bokeh socket python

Tags: python, sockets, real-time, bokeh

I'm trying to understand how to work with bokeh-server to display a real-time plot using sockets. So far I created two files to run into two separate windows in order to simulate the stream of data to be sent.

I have a client.py that sends an array containing 3 elements:

```
import sys
import time
import socket
from pylab import randn


# Create a TCP/IP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# Connect the socket to the port where the server is listening
server_address = ('localhost', 2000)
sock.connect(server_address)

try:
    for i in xrange(100):
        m = randn(3)
        message = m.tostring()
        print >>sys.stderr, 'sending "%s"' % m
        sock.sendall(message)
        time.sleep(0.01)

finally:
    print >>sys.stderr, 'closing socket'
    sock.close()
```

I have also a server.py which receives the data and updates the plot in the bokeh-server.

```
import sys
import time
import socket
from pylab import *
from bokeh.plotting import cursession, figure, show, output_server


output_server("raw_values")

# Visualization workflow
counter = 0
rx = [0]
ry = [0]
rz = [0]
p = figure()
x = [0]
p.line(x, rx, name='raw_mx')

# Create a TCP/IP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# Bind the socket to the port
server_address = ('localhost', 2000)
print >>sys.stderr, 'starting up on %s port %s' % server_address
sock.bind(server_address)

# Listen for incoming connections
sock.listen(1)

renderer = p.select(dict(name="raw_mx"))
ds = renderer[0].data_source

show(p)

while True:
    # Wait for a connection
    print >>sys.stderr, 'waiting for a connection'
    connection, client_address = sock.accept()

    try:
        print >>sys.stderr, 'connection from', client_address

        while True:
            data = fromstring(connection.recv(24))
            print data

            if len(data) == 0:
                break

            rx += [data[0]]
            ry += [data[1]]
            rz += [data[2]]
            x += [counter]
            counter += 1

            ds.data["x"] = x
            ds.data["rmag_x"] = rx
            cursession().store_objects(ds)
            time.sleep(0.01)


    finally:
        # Clean up the connection
        connection.close()
```

I do confirm I have the bokeh-server running. I'm receiving the following error. By troubleshooting I believe this errors occurs somehow due to the `show(p)` as if I comment that line I have no error, the data is sent and received. However, the plot is not updated since the `show(p)` is not present.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/user/Documents/server.py in <module>()
     36     # Wait for a connection
     37     print >>sys.stderr, 'waiting for a connection'
---> 38     connection, client_address = sock.accept()
     39 
     40     try:

/home/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/socket.pyc in accept(self)
    204 
    205     def accept(self):
--> 206         sock, addr = self._sock.accept()
    207         return _socketobject(_sock=sock), addr
    208     accept.__doc__ = _realsocket.accept.__doc__

error: [Errno 4] Interrupted system call

In [38]: 
(process:13045): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
```

Answer (score 0):

The error was due to some network settings misconfiguration that were preventing the server to work properly. The code is working nice right now.